# Auctex: Fold all environments of a specific type in a buffer

Tags: auctex, code-folding

With auctex I can run `TeX-fold-env` the environment on which point currently is located.

How can I fold all environments `foo` (`\begin{foo}... \end{foo}`) in my buffer at once? And how to unfold all occurences of `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun latex-fold-foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((env (read-from-minibuffer "Environment: ")))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (format "begin{%s}" env) nil t)
        (TeX-fold-env)))))
```

Comment: Please some explanation in addition to just code